# How to skip some axis labels but keep ticks in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to skip every Nth label on the axis but keep the ticks in matplotlib ([just like y-axis in this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFase.png)).
Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is the code I have:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[4, 5.5])

xax  = np.arange(0, 120, 20)
yax  = np.arange(1, 13, 1)
data = yax**1.8

ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(1, 12)
ax.set_xticks(xax)
ax.set_yticks(yax)
ax.set_xticklabels(xax, fontsize=11)
ax.set_yticklabels(yax, fontsize=11)

ax.plot(data, yax, c='blue')
ax.grid(which='major', color='black',  linewidth=0.1, alpha=0.6)
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=600)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get the similar figure you provided, I would add this two lines:

```
yticks_label = ['{}'.format(num) if num % 2 != 0 else ' ' for num in yax]
plt.yticks(yax, yticks_label, fontsize=11)
```

and delete this line:

```
ax.set_yticklabels(yax, fontsize=11)
```

I ran it in my machine, it gives this figure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works for this specific case (remove even numbers). However, it seems matplotlib does not have a command to skip some labels.

Comment: I had the same feeling when I gradually realized those facts. Let's say, screen monitor, if we only move mouse in one little corner, regular people might think, "oh, the CPU just needs to control the pixel value on one little corner", but in fact, the rest of the area is also computed, refreshed with the same rate as that little corner, just with the same color value. Same for this case, "skip" is just how it looks, but behind the scene, we control the "skipped part" using ` ` (empty value).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but you could look into minor ticks.

```
ax.tick_params(which='major', length=7)
ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=4, color='r')
```

And then customize these values to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jason's answer: Use list comprehension, modulus, and enumerate.

```
yax = ax.get_yticks()
yticks_label = [f"{num}" if i % 2 !=0 else '' for i,num in enumerate(yax)]
ax.set_yticks(yax, yticks_label)
```